# iAds trough adWhirl not fully loading

Tags: ios, iad, adwhirl

I just implemented adWhirl to my app with iAds and adMob. Everything compiles correctly and adMob works perfectly, but my iAd's are not being sized correctly. the ad looks like its the right size, but it actually appears to be cut off. About 1/4 of the ad seems like it is missing. Since i have no bugs i don't know exactly where to look to fix this.

here is a screenshot of what my ad bar looks like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUexq.jpg

any help or just a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated!

here is the AdWhirlAdapteriAd.h

```
#import "AdWhirlAdNetworkAdapter.h"
#import <iAd/ADBannerView.h>

@interface AdWhirlAdapterIAd : AdWhirlAdNetworkAdapter <ADBannerViewDelegate> {
  NSString *kADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
  NSString *kADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
}

+ (AdWhirlAdNetworkType)networkType;

@end
```

here is AdWhirlAdapteriAd.m

```
#import "AdWhirlAdapterIAd.h"
#import "AdWhirlAdNetworkConfig.h"
#import "AdWhirlView.h"
#import "AdWhirlLog.h"
#import "AdWhirlAdNetworkAdapter+Helpers.h"
#import "AdWhirlAdNetworkRegistry.h"

@implementation AdWhirlAdapterIAd

+ (AdWhirlAdNetworkType)networkType {
  return AdWhirlAdNetworkTypeIAd;
}

+ (void)load {
  if(NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView") != nil) {
    [[AdWhirlAdNetworkRegistry sharedRegistry] registerClass:self];
  }
}

- (void)getAd {
  ADBannerView *iAdView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
  kADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait =
    &ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait != nil ?
      ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait :
      ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
  kADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape =
    &ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape != nil ?
      ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape :
      ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
  iAdView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                                        kADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait,
                                        kADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape,
                                        nil];
  UIDeviceOrientation orientation;
  if ([self.adWhirlDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(adWhirlCurrentOrientation)]) {
orientation = [self.adWhirlDelegate adWhirlCurrentOrientation];
  }
  else {
    orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
  }

  if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
    iAdView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = kADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
  }
  else {
    iAdView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = kADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
  }
  [iAdView setDelegate:self];

  self.adNetworkView = iAdView;
  [iAdView release];
}

- (void)stopBeingDelegate {
  ADBannerView *iAdView = (ADBannerView *)self.adNetworkView;
  if (iAdView != nil) {
    iAdView.delegate = nil;
  }
}

- (void)rotateToOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
  ADBannerView *iAdView = (ADBannerView *)self.adNetworkView;
  if (iAdView == nil) return;
  if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
    iAdView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = kADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape;
  }
  else {
    iAdView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = kADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
  }
  // ADBanner positions itself in the center of the super view, which we do not
  // want, since we rely on publishers to resize the container view.
  // position back to 0,0
  CGRect newFrame = iAdView.frame;
  newFrame.origin.x = newFrame.origin.y = 0;
  iAdView.frame = newFrame;
}

- (BOOL)isBannerAnimationOK:(AWBannerAnimationType)animType {
  if (animType == AWBannerAnimationTypeFadeIn) {
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark IAdDelegate methods

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
  // ADBanner positions itself in the center of the super view, which we do not
  // want, since we rely on publishers to resize the container view.
  // position back to 0,0
  CGRect newFrame = banner.frame;
  newFrame.origin.x = newFrame.origin.y = 0;
  banner.frame = newFrame;

  [adWhirlView adapter:self didReceiveAdView:banner];
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
  [adWhirlView adapter:self didFailAd:error];
}

- (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:              (BOOL)willLeave {
  [self helperNotifyDelegateOfFullScreenModal];
  return YES;
}

- (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner {
  [self helperNotifyDelegateOfFullScreenModalDismissal];
}

@end
```

Here is where the ads are being called in the app

MainMenuInterface.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "GameManager.h"
#import "AdWhirlView.h"
#import "AdWhirlDelegateProtocol.h"
#import "Reading_FluencyAppDelegate.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"

enum GameStatePP {
    kGameStatePlaying,
    kGameStatePaused
};


@interface MainMenuInterface : CCLayer <AdWhirlDelegate>

{
    CCMenu *mainMenu;
    CCMenu *aboutPage;

    RootViewController *viewController;
    AdWhirlView *adWhirlView;
    enum GameStatePP _state;
}

@property(nonatomic,retain) AdWhirlView *adWhirlView;
@property(nonatomic) enum GameStatePP state;

-(void)displayStartButton;

@end
```

and here is the important stuff in MainMenuInterface.m

```
- (void)adWhirlWillPresentFullScreenModal {

    if (self.state == kGameStatePlaying) {

        //[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] pauseBackgroundMusic];

        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
  }
}

- (void)adWhirlDidDismissFullScreenModal {

    if (self.state == kGameStatePaused)
        return;

    else {
        self.state = kGameStatePlaying;
        //[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] resumeBackgroundMusic];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];

    }
}

- (NSString *)adWhirlApplicationKey {
    return @"23myapplicationkey39203924";
}

- (UIViewController *)viewControllerForPresentingModalView {
    return viewController;
}

-(void)adjustAdSize {
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"AdResize" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
    CGSize adSize = [adWhirlView actualAdSize];
    CGRect newFrame = adWhirlView.frame;
newFrame.size.height = adSize.height;

CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
newFrame.size.width = winSize.width;
newFrame.origin.x = (self.adWhirlView.bounds.size.width - adSize.width)/2;

newFrame.origin.y = (winSize.height - adSize.height);
adWhirlView.frame = newFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)adWhirlDidReceiveAd:(AdWhirlView *)adWhirlVieww {
[adWhirlView rotateToOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
[self adjustAdSize];

}

-(void)onEnter {
    viewController = [(Reading_FluencyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]         delegate] viewController];
    self.adWhirlView = [AdWhirlView requestAdWhirlViewWithDelegate:self];
    self.adWhirlView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;

    [adWhirlView updateAdWhirlConfig];
CGSize adSize = [adWhirlView actualAdSize];
CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
self.adWhirlView.frame = CGRectMake((winSize.width/2)-(adSize.width/2),winSize.height-            adSize.height,winSize.width,adSize.height);
self.adWhirlView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[viewController.view addSubview:adWhirlView];
[viewController.view bringSubviewToFront:adWhirlView];
[super onEnter];
}

-(void)onExit {
if (adWhirlView) {
    [adWhirlView removeFromSuperview];
    [adWhirlView replaceBannerViewWith:nil];
    [adWhirlView ignoreNewAdRequests];
    [adWhirlView setDelegate:nil];
    self.adWhirlView = nil;
}
[super onExit];
}

-(void)dealloc
{
self.adWhirlView.delegate = nil;
self.adWhirlView = nil;
[super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: You need to show iAd code to check whats wrong. snapshot wouldn't be enough.

Comment: updated with code that i thought was relevant. let me know if you need the app delegate codes aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those that need to know in the future, my problem turned out to be that it was calling ads for landscape instead of portrait, than when it called adjustAdSize() it wasnt getting correct sizing.

i changed

```
- (void)adWhirlDidReceiveAd:(AdWhirlView *)adWhirlVieww {
    [adWhirlView rotateToOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    [self adjustAdSize];
{
```

to

```
- (void)adWhirlDidReceiveAd:(AdWhirlView *)adWhirlVieww {
    [adWhirlView rotateToOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
    [self adjustAdSize];
{
```

and it fixed all my problems!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the `winSize` property for your `sharedDirector` still thinks your in portrait? What if you flipped it so you had:

```
newFrame.size.width = winSize.height;
newFrame.origin.x = (self.adWhirlView.bounds.size.width - adSize.width)/2;

newFrame.origin.y = (winSize.width - adSize.height);
adWhirlView.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, trying these changes helped me realize that it was calling for a landscape ad size instead of a portrait ad size.